# Linq strongly typed datacontext will not compile

Tags: linq-to-sql, datacontext

I am trying to fetch all data from a SQL Server table using a strongly typed LINQ To SQL datacontext, as per this MSDN example: [How to: Connect to a Database (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399375.aspx)

My code is as follows:

```
    public class bioAppointments
    {
        string _strConnString = "Data Source=local; Initial Catalog=MyDatabase; User Id=MyUser; Password=MyPassword;";

        public List<Appointment> getAllAppointments()
        {

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_strConnString);

            Appt dc = new Appt(connection);
            var query =
                from appt in dc.myAppointments
                select new Appointment
                {
                    AppointmentId = appt.AppointmentId,
                    StartDate = appt.StartDate,
                    EndDate = appt.EndDate,
                    StartTime = appt.StartTime,
                    EndTime = appt.EndTime,
                    Notes = appt.Notes,
                };

            return query.ToList();
        }

        public partial class Appt : DataContext
        {
            public Table<Appointments> myAppointments;
            public Appt(string connection) : base(connection) { }
        }

        public class Appointment
        {
            public int AppointmentId { get; set; }
            public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
            public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
            public String Notes { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

I am getting a compile error:

> The type or namespace name 'Appointments' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The squiggle is under  in the *Appt* class.

Does anyone know what this is means and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
   public Table<Appointments> myAppointments;
```

shouldn't it be this? (Singular)

```
   public Table<Appointment> myAppointments;
```

Comment: Yes, it should.  The ORM de-pluralizes the table name for individual objects by default. +1